# Using Sphinx for documenting projects and modules on demand

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I use [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) for documenting a Python module. I have a master `doc` directory, where I put individual `*.rst` files (on for each module component) to be included in the `index.rst` main file. That works great (please check the [source of the Python Library Reference](http://docs.python.org/_sources/library/index.txt) to see exactly how I do it).

My problem is when I need to create a standalone PDF for a given module component (as opposed to the whole module).

Say you have the same structure as in the [Python Library Reference](http://docs.python.org/_sources/library/index.txt) for your full module (library), and you then one to create a standalone PDF for the documentation of, say, the `crypto` component. What would you do?

1. Create a different index (`index_2.rst`) and include only that file (`crypto.rst`)
2. Comment the other files from the original `index.rst`
3. Create a whole new doc directory inside the `crypto` with standalone Sphinx documentation

None of these approaches seem straightforward.

Advice, please.

Comment: You might be better off asking the question here: http://groups.google.com/group/sphinx-dev . Although there are lots of questions on S.O. tagged 'sphinx' most are nothing to do with the Python documentation tool. :(

Answer (score 2):

First I would create a template, such as `index_template.rst`. Next I would write a shell script that takes one parameter. This parameter would specify the component you want to generate, otherwise it generates an index.rst for all components.

Then customize your [Makefile to support a component parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783098/makefile-parameter). The Makefile would pass this parameter to the shell script that generates a new `index.rst` each time.

This would allow you to do something like:

```
$ make html
$ make html component=crypto
```

The first command would generate a document for everything and the second would generate just the `crypto` component.