# Parameter for rule in Makefile

Tags: unix, makefile

I need to make a Makefile, and it should have a `run` rule. However, the run requires some parameters.

Does anyone have any idea how I can pass arguments in when running a rule in a Makefile? I want to be able to run the `run` rule with arguments by typing `make run foo bar`.

I tried this, but it didn’t work:

```
run:
    make compile
    ./scripts/runTrips $1 $2 $PLACES $OUT $VERS
```

The parameters I want supplied are the first and the second.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When passing parameters to a make command, reference them like you would other internal make variables.

If your makefile looks like:

```
run:
        script $(param1) $(param2)
```

You can call it with the following syntax:

```
$> make run param1=20 param2=30
```

and make should call the script like:

```
script 20 30
```

Comment: it actually works, but can I make it run when I write:
$> make run <param1> <param2>  (and not param1=<param1> .... )

Comment: @amit gr: No, something like `make run <param1>` is not possible because `make` wants to interpret it as a target name. Consider for example `make all install`: first the target "all" is processed, then the target "install". Everything that you want to be a kind of parameter has to be passed via the `key=value` syntax (or environment variables of the same name).

Answer (score 5):

Make itself doesn't provide passing arguments like for scripts. Usually make is used in the following way: you configure project than run just simple 'make'. Configuring can be done by running shell script 'configure'. This script is the one that you can pass parameters to. For example:

```
./configure param1 param2
make run
```

configure script must parse parameters and write them out to config.mk. config.mk must contain the following:

```
PARAM1 = val1
PARAM2 = val2
```

Your Makefile must include config.mk:

```
TOP = .
include $(TOP)/config.mk

run:
    make compile
    ./scripts/runTrips $(PARAM1) $(PARAM2) $(PLACES) $(OUT) $(VERS)
```

In your 'configure' script you can also check parameters for correctness and make other checks and calculations.